# ASP.NET Form Authentication and Token Authentication in same set of applications - SSO

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, single-sign-on, forms-authentication, jwt

I need all your inputs for a use case with SSO implementation. Let me explain you my use case. I have couple of applications which written way back in 2004 – 2005 with ASP.NET, C#, SQL etc.. and uses ASP.NET cookie based Form Authentication to maintain the SSO between these web applications. It is working great and no issues so far. Now in early 2015, we are in the initial stage of building next generation application using HTML5, Angular JS & Web API which should work in all platforms & devices. So we decided to move with JWT Token based authentication in the new applications to maintain the SSO between. But the curtail use case pitch in now that is, the new set of application also should allow user to go back to their old applications by not asking any login information ( eventually, SSO between new applications vs old application). Since both uses different way of authentication, it is not going to be a straight forward implementation (My guess ).

Would any of you come across such situation before? Any suggestions?. Advance thanks for all of you.!!